# How to install Git on Solaris 10?

Tags: git, solaris-10

My query is regarding installing Git on Solaris 10. `uname -a` gives

```
bash-3.00# uname -a
SunOS 5.10 Generic_141444-09 sun4u sparc SUNW,Sun-Fire-V240
```

I want to use Solaris server as Git central repository while Windows based users to use the git repository on Solaris server for project activities. What are the steps for installation? What I need to install for users on Windows platform so they can use git?

Comment: You should ask a specific question for a particular programming problem. Since Stack Overflow hides the Close reason from you: *"Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it."*

Answer (score 9):

On Solaris, you can follow the instruction on [opencsw](http://www.opencsw.org/package/git/) or [git-scm](http://git-scm.com/download/linux) to install Git.
On windows, you can download the install package from [official page](http://git-scm.com/download/win), but currently, git on Solaris is 2.x, on windows it's 1.x, maybe there're small differences between them, but I don't think it's a big deal.

Alternatively, on windows, you can install 3rd party git client, such as [Tortoise Git](https://code.google.com/p/tortoisegit/) or [SourceTree](http://sourcetreeapp.com/).

Next, Windows-based users need to use the git repository on Solaris, so it's necessary to learn how to build a git server, you can refer to relative chapter in [git book](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-on-the-Server).