# Git Client package name for Solaris 10

Tags: git, github, installation, solaris

We are in process of moving our code to bitbucket. To perform checkouts and build we use unix machine with Solaris-10 OS and we need to install git-client on that machine.
I specifically require to find the packages available (basically package-names) for git client which I can provide to the tools team to install. Can someone help me with a few Git client package names compatible for Solaris OS.

Note-1: I have gone through [How to install Git on Solaris 10?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24628592/how-to-install-git-on-solaris-10) link but could not find package names but rather just the install process. 
Note-2: I myself can not install (due to privileges) git on the machine.
Note-3: uname -a gives below output
SunOS  5.10 Generic_150400-34 sun4v sparc sun4v

Comment: Is it `CSWgit`, per https://www.opencsw.org/package/git/ ?

Comment: @QZSupport seems ok, but I will check this with tool team and post back in case of further queries. Thanks.

Comment: @peterh Solaris 10 is supported by Oracle until 2021.  Please don't make assumptions about "how difficult" an OS upgrade is or worse what a particular client "needs".  It's irrelevant to the question. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solaris_(operating_system)#Version_history

Comment: Finally got confirmation from tool team that  there is no git client support for solaris. So  I have to move to Linux . I will post a separate question on a rpm dependency issue I am facing. :)